# How do I create a named set of interfaces by name in nftables?

Tags: nftables

Using sets in [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/) is really cool. I am currently using a lot of statements like these in my `nftables.conf` rulesets:

```
iifname {clients0, dockernet} oifname wan0 accept \
    comment "Allow clients and Docker containers to reach the internet"
```

In the rule above `{clients0, dockernet}` is an *anonymous* (inline) set of interfaces. Instead of repetition in the rules over and over, I'd like to define a set of interfaces at the top of the file, called a [*named set*](http://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets) in nftables. The [manpage (Debian Buster)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/nftables/nftables.8.en.html#SETS) shows how to do that for several types of sets: *ipv4_addr*, *ipv6_addr*, *ether_addr*, *inet_proto*, *inet_service* and *mark*. However, it seems it's not available for interfaces by name or simple primitive type such as strings.

I've the approach below, but this does not work with the errors given:

1. Omitting the type:

   ```
   table inet filter {
     set myset {
       elements = {
         clients0,
         dockernet,           
       }
     }
     [...]
   }
   ```

   Result: `Error: set definition does not specify key`.
2. Using the `string` type:

   ```
   table inet filter {
     type string;
     set myset {
       elements = {
         clients0,
         dockernet,           
       }
     }
     [...]
   }
   ```

   Result: `Error: unqualified key type string specified in set definition`.

Is there really no way of naming the anonymous set I've shown on the top?

Comment: `type string;` must be within the brackets of `set myset {}` in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By searching in the [source for version 0.9.0](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/src/datatype.c?h=v0.9.0#n32):

> ```
> static const struct datatype *datatypes[TYPE_MAX + 1] = {
> ```

[...]

> ```
>   [TYPE_IFINDEX]      = &ifindex_type,
> ```

[...]

> ```
>   [TYPE_IFNAME]       = &ifname_type,
> };
> ```

and then looking for where they [are](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/src/meta.c?h=v0.9.0#n170) [defined](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/src/meta.c?h=v0.9.0#n377):

> ```
> const struct datatype ifindex_type = {
>   .type       = TYPE_IFINDEX,
>   .name       = "iface_index",
>   .desc       = "network interface index",
> ```

[...]

> ```
> const struct datatype ifname_type = {
>   .type       = TYPE_IFNAME,
>   .name       = "ifname",
>   .desc       = "network interface name",
> ```

it's possible to find that the needed types are `iface_index` (eg: `iif lo`) and `ifname` (eg `iifname "lo"`), even if (as of writing this answer) it's [undocumented in `nft`'s man page](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/manpage.html#lbAS).

```
nft add set inet filter if-index-set '{ type iface_index;  }'
nft add set inet filter if-name-set '{ type ifname;  }'

nft add element inet filter if-index-set '{ lo }'
nft add element inet filter if-name-set '{ lo }'

nft add chain inet filter input '{ type filter hook input priority 0; }'
nft add rule inet filter input iif @if-index-set counter
nft add rule inet filter input iifname @if-name-set counter
```

---

Note that *ifname* wildcard support in a set has been added on 2022-05-31 in [nftables 1.0.3](https://lwn.net/Articles/896732/). A named set must use `flags intervals` and the final wildcard character is `*` (not `+` like in *iptables*).

Answer (score 3):

The element datatype can be easily found using `nft` like this:

```
$ nft describe iifname    
meta expression, datatype ifname (network interface name) (basetype string), 16 characters
% nft describe iif    
meta expression, datatype iface_index (network interface index) (basetype integer), 32 bits
```

You see that `ifname` and `iface_index` are the possible types, so **you can just declare**:

```
 set myset {
    type ifname
    elements = {
       "clients0",  
       "dockernet"  
    }       
 }
```

In the above example, you can even write `typeof iifname` instead of `type ifname` if you don't know about the type (requires `nft` v0.9.4 or above).